# Update RichTextBox using Static methods

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to update a `RichTextBox` control from multiple `static methods`. A lot of text is to be added every time and in a very fast interval of time. This is a Client-Sever kind of application and a dll is utilizing the static handlers. I'm using the following code and none of text is being added in the RichTextBox from static methods. How do I fix this?

```
    public partial class MyMainForm : Form
    {
        private static MyMainForm FrmReference;

        private static void Handler1(object parameter, ConnectionEvent CE)
        {
            FrmReference.MyRichTextBox.AppendText(DateTime.Now + "....x....");
        }

        private static void Handler2(object parameter, DataEvent DE)
        {
            FrmReference.MyRichTextBox.AppendText(DateTime.Now + "....y....");
        }

        public MyMainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FrmReference = this;

        }

        private void VNToolStripButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new Connection("127.0.0.1", ConParams);
            con.SetConnectionHandler(Handler1, null);
            con.SetDataHandler(Handler2, null);

            MyRichTextBox.AppendText(DateTime.Now + "....abc....");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you verify that your Handlers are called?

Comment: Where are you calling Handler1 and Handler2 from?  It is not shown in your code

Comment: What is the reason behind this _static_ choice for your methods?

Comment: Ok, actually I forgot to add that part while keeping the question short! but yes they are being called by the dll in the background and doing what they are intended to do. They are defined here in the following way:
con = new Connection("127.0.0.1", ConParams); 
con.SetConnectionHandler(Handler1, null);
con.SetDataHandler(Handler2, null);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handlers aren't called.

If you try something like this, you'll see **that the problem isn't the static method** that should write into the `RichTextBox`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static Form1 frmReference;

    private static void WriteToMyRichTextBox(string what)
    {
        frmReference.richTextBox1.AppendText(what);
        frmReference.richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frmReference = this;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WriteToMyRichTextBox(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The Handlers are being called, please refer to the updated question. The issue seems to be the speed of the asynchronous calls (almost < 1 sec) or the accessibility of the RichTextBox control for all these operations.

Comment: @Varun Try to put a `Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: Handler called");` inside your handlers, and show the results

Comment: Thanks for the help! The issue was inside a part of code of the Handler itself. The Console.Writeline helped in easy debugging. Also I implemented this method WriteToMyRichTextBox(string what) and made sure that all the append text operations are preformed via this methdod. Everything working fine now. Thanks!